# hiding MS Word row if record is empty

Tags: vba, ms-word

i'm creating a word template form my Dynamics 365 Quote template.

[image]

i want to hide the entire total row if msdyn_totalamount is empty or returns an empty value. is that possible in MS word?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/44940-hide-row-ms-word-table-if-one.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759261/hiding-row-in-dynamics-365-template-table-if-record-is-empty